# is it possible to get online incoming messages from users in telegram (not bot)?

Tags: flutter, api, telegram, message

I need to get all incoming messages from all possible social media and redirect them in one app, using this protocol https://pusher.com/docs/channels/library_auth_reference/pusher-websockets-protocol/, I've read about getting messages in telegram API, but it's possible only with bots.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [telegram-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=telegram-cli) yet?

Comment: I guess it's no longer supported. Just got `API_64BIT_LOGIN_APP_OUTDATED_254: You are using an outdated app that is no longer supported`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon is a Python 3 library which works both with regular users and bots